# Javascript: date obj-date obj

Tags: javascript, date

As example. I want to check if time at t1 to now is more than 10s. How can I check it in angular js. I get now then substract t1. It return a number. How to convert it to second

Comment: That number is in millsecond, divided by 1000 is what your want

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for my Date object. It is a high level library, framework-orgnistic, and match very well with angular template system using [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment).

In your case you just should do it like this :

```
var t1 = moment();
... wait 10 sec ...
if (t1.fromNow('s') >= 10) {
   ...
}
```

It make is very easy to maintain in time, BUT cost some ressources if used to much.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript solution:

```
function checkAgo(t1, agoSecs) {
    var timeAgo = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000 * agoSecs);
    return t1 < timeAgo;
}
```

Call the function this way: `checkAgo(t1, 10)`.